# Formatting Excel when exporting via header

Tags: php, html, export-to-excel

Personally I've never used this method before and I havent been able to find any information to help me.
The page I'm updating uses the following to export a html table as an Excel file.

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Target-Report.xls"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
```

It generates the file just fine, I just need to make the report more presentable.
Is there a way to set Cell type in Excel (i.e. Percentage) and set decimal places (in cells where I've created excel formulas).

I'd prefer to use PHPExcel, but I dont have time to practically rewrite the entire script

Comment: Modify your formulas to use the MS Excel ROUND() function, but I'm not sure how to simulate percentage display without actually changing the value in your HTML table

Comment: I could use ROUND(), but it loses accuracy for other fields. Unfortunately I need to allow for formula to work (for manual changes)

Comment: Come to think of it, worse comes to worse I could convert to % my self: `=ROUND(C5/C6, 0) & "%"`.  It will allow me to do percentages but that doesnt solve setting decimal places for other fields